# MVC - Handling Multiple records in a single page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I have a MVC page where an Employee drop-down will be there and below there is a partial page where I have an input form. When the user selects an employee the user can edit the form and he can choose the next employee. After editing all the employees he will hit the submit button. Already I am using this form in one another page and I have a model for this. But since multiple records are involved in this page I am not sure how to build the model. Please give some suggestions on how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to send a set of models to a page instead of a single model, you would pass an `IEnumerable<YourModel>`

in the top of your view you can have this:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourModel>
```

Then use it in a loop like this:

```
@foreach(YourModel ym in Model)
{
    // pass ym to a partial view or render with with cshtml here..
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neil. I think IEnumerable<YourModel> will help. However I cannot use a @foreach right? I am going to display the input form for the current employee (dropdown selected index). I am sorry I am new to MVC. Apologies If anything asked very silly.

Comment: I guess I would have to see your page layout.  Perhaps send a SelectList along in the ViewBag to populate the drop down. Then in the foreach I showed above, have it create a div for each employee, but leave them hidden.  Then on the client side, enable the appropriate div when the drop down changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an Ajax form with the drop-down list of employees, and set the ajax form to update your partial when submitted (an employee is chosen).  The Ajax form will fire a controller action which grabs the details of the person selected and populates the partial form below which has the employee details.  You can then submit the partial.

However this means submitting changes on each employee as they are made, so you would select one employee, edit the details and submit your changes.  Then select the next employee.

In a bit of a rush so no code but if you require some I will provide a more comprehensive answer tomorrow, just let me know.